# Prerendering failed because of error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'getDOM' of undefined

Tags: angular

**Error while upgrading Angular 2.o to Angular 4.0**

```
Exception: Call to Node module failed with error: Prerendering failed because of error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'getDOM' of undefined
    at Object. (D:\Angularplayapp\node_modules\angular2-platform-node\get-dom.js:3:61) at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object. (D:\Angularplayapp\node_modules\angular2-platform-node\index.js:5:17)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
```

Comment: Which version angular2-platform-node are you using? Try @2.1.0-rc.1

Comment: Also experiencing the same issue - you get this sorted?